# Laravel blade and @ escape as a text

Tags: php, laravel

I have two variables that I want print them in Laravel blade template as a text with `@` sign. Suppose the following:

`$var1 = 1500
$var2 = 50.51`

So I want print them to be `Production is: 1500@50.51%`
I have tried:

`Production is: {{$var1}}@{{$var2}}%`

The above code generates:

`Production is: 1500{{$var2}}%`

I could not able to find any escape for `@` other than printing it as a string like the following:

`Production is: {{$var1}}{{'@'}}{{$var2}}%`

So, is there any way to escape @ in blade template?

Comment: You can have a space between the variables and @ `{{$var1}} @ {{$var2}}`

Comment: `{{$var1}}&#64;{{$var2}}`

Comment: `{{$var1}}@<!-- -->{{$var2}}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use :

```
Production is: {{ $var1 .'@'. $var2 }}%
```

Simplest way to do what you want.

Comment: Probably the best way